# Twitter API integration with static website

Tags: json, twitter

I'm new to Twitter, I have a static website, I want to implement latest twitter API 1.1 which should provide me json result to my website.

I have tried multiple things but no success.

Kindly provide me step by step guild what should I do.

Comment: "Multiple things" is always a good thing to try. Actually telling *what* you have tried is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find javascript library on this page to integrate in static website.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Good Luck.

Comment: read the document. They have described in very easy and step by step. If you read carefully, you will get it work. :)

Comment: I want to do this using jquery, but i don't know whether this is possible with ver 1.1 or not. If Possible can you pls provide sample codebase or any reference site.

Comment: here is the link to implement twitter with jquery: https://github.com/StanScates/Tweet.js-Mod. Kindly mark as accepted if this is helpful so it will help out others to identify that this question is solved. :) thank you.